# Which is proper way to update database at specific time every day?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have to parse some data every day at 10 AM, and to put data in a ORMLite database. Which is proper way to do this? Should I use a service?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you google what to use for running background tasks?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I don't understand which is the best way, I found so many options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if it helps you out,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10); // For 10 AM
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MyClass.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Comment: MyClass should have a main method, which will do database update?

Comment: In that case you need to manage proper context no main method is needed.

Comment: I did not understand too well, when I should call the update method?

Comment: @FilipRosca MyClass extends Service. Google how to implement a Service on Android.

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec but here is a problem, what if at 10 AM network will not be available?

Comment: @FilipRosca That's why you use GcmNetworkManager instead.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `AlarmManager`or `Service`.

**Alarm Manager**
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

**Service**
[Example1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm),[Example2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

Comment: How? Please include code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Thank you.